# How to find out which groups do I belong to, has to be done using /etc/group

Tags: linux, unix

I did do:

```
groups UserName
```

It did give me the groups where I do belong to, but how can I find this out, by using `/etc/group` in my command?

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/group`,

`cut -d":" -f1,4 /etc/group | grep user`